# How to create a view to display ALL HTTP errors in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel to build a website, and I want to have custom views for HTTP errors.

I found that I have to create an `errors` folder in the `views` folder, and then create a file per error like so:

```
> views
    > errors
        - 404.blade.php
        - 504.blade.php
        ...
```

I am not done if I want to handle all errors...
Moreover, I just want to use the same view to display all errors, with only the error number and error message to change.

What I would like is to have one view only, with one variable $code (the HTTP error code), for all HTTP errors.

```
<h1 id='code'>{{ $code }}</h1>
<p id='message'>{{ $messages[$code] }}</p>
```

`$message` is some kind of global or config variable.

So question is actually how to redirect all HTTP errors in a single view with the value of the error code ?

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-laravel-404-page-using-custom-exception-handlers

Answer (score 1):

In the render method in exception class you can have something like this

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{

        return response()->view('errors.'.$e->getStatusCode(), [], $e->getStatusCode());

}
```

Comment: OP wants one file for everything, so it's probably going to be more like plain old `response()->view('errors')`. Maybe passing `$e` to that view, but the per-status code approach you propose is already *default* in Laravel. That said, this answer at least points OP to the right spot to do it.

Comment: return response()->view('errors', ['code'=>$e->getStatusCode(), 'message'=>$e->getMessage()], $e->getStatusCode());